# Use of \csname in \input produces mysterious results

Tags: macros, input

I am stuck with the following one where I want to input a file with a name in the line of `\jobnameQ.tex`.

Here is my MWE excerpted from a bigger picture.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\def\csinput{\expandafter\input{\csname\jobname Q.tex\endcsname}}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname Q.tex}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{filecontents}

\csinput

\end{document}
```

This does not input any file and does not produce any output.

However, I know that if I define `\csinput` in the manner

```
\def\csinput#1{\input{\jobname#1.tex}}
```

and call it like this, 
`\csinput{Q}` it will work.

I would like to know why the first methodology does not work. (And how it can be remedied.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `\csname \jobname Q.tex\endcsname` expands to `\nameQ.tex`, i.e. to the control sequence which is not defined. The undefined control sequences constructed by `\csname...\endcsname` have `\relax` meaning. The `\expandafter` in your code is redundant because `{` isn't expanable. The `\input` is a macro in the LaTeX. The `\input{something}` expands to the primitive `\input something`. Because the `something` here has a meaning `\relax`, the following TeX primitive command is processed:

```
\input \relax
```

Because the name of the file in `\input` primitive command can be delimited by another unexpandable primitive command (for example `\relax`), we have empty filename here. TeX appends to this empty filename the `.tex` suffix and performs to read `.tex` file. This file is present in typical TeX distributions with the contents: `\message{File ignored}`.

The result: this file is read and the message is printed.

**Note** I try to explain why the `.tex` file mentioned above is present in the TeX distributions. TeX stops when it finds an error (in `\errorstopmode` which is common setting) and waits to the user response. The typical user response is only "press Enter" which continues processing. But there is another type of error: `I can't find file ...`. If user responses by Enter and the `.tex` doesn't exist then the error is printed again and again because only the real file name must be entered here. This would make a user irritation. The `.tex` file is read when user hit Enter in this situation and the process continues. This is similar behavior as in "normal" errors.

Comment: Is there a way out of the situation? That is, is there a way to input the file in the manner I want? And how `filecontents` handles the scenario of a similar kind?

Comment: @Masroor: Just drop the surrounding `\csname`...`\endcsname`. Technically you also don't need the `\expandafter`, as `\def\csinput{\input{\jobname Q.tex}}` works fine.

Comment: @Masroor Why are you trying to do expansion when it's not required? As wipet has explained, your `\csname` stuff means TeX is looking for a file name that does not exist. As you've already found, the second version works just fine as TeX expands `\jobname` as part of constructing the file name.

Comment: @Werner That was the first solution I tried and it did not work with a message like undefined `\jobnameQ` or some such. Now I realize that solution must have been different from my line of thoughts. I can not locate my mistake in that first thought solution because the file has been changed so many times. (And I feel like deleting my question since I have made an easy thing difficult. But I will leave it in that manner since the answer from wipet points out the important issue of `\relax` in `\csname` which I was not aware off).

Comment: Maybe there is another enlightenment: read the terminal messages and log file. The message about reading of `.tex` file is here. This means that isn't true: "TeX does not input any file".

Comment: @wipet Yes, I saw that message without comprehension, now you make me understand that.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose `\jobname` has the value of `test`. Then `\csname\jobname Q.tex\endcsname` represents a macro with the name `testQ.tex`, just as `\csname jobname\endcsname` represents a macro with the name `jobname`.

The macro with a name `testQ.tex` (which would be written `\testQ.tex` if you could have dots in macro names) doesn't exist, so `\input` will not get the filename you want to give it.

Basically, you shouldn't use `\csname` here. You don't need a macro with the same name as the file, you need a macro (well, a macro plus some other stuff) whose *value* is the filename. Just this:

```
\def\csinput{\input{\jobname Q.tex}}
```